# shortcode // get posts by ids

Tags: posts, functions, shortcode

I am looking for a solution to display custom posts in a shortcode. For one post this already works as desired, however I would like to specify multiple IDs. like: [posts id=1, 2, 3,4]
Cause I come from the frontend area, I lack the approach how I would have to adapt the function accordingly and hope that someone here has a solution for me.

```
add_shortcode( 'posts', 'posts_shortcode' );
function posts_shortcode($atts) {
    
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => ''
    ), $atts );
    
    $post_id = $atts['id'];
    
    $HTML  = '<div class="posts">';
    $HTML .= '<div class="thumb">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'medium') . '</div>';
    $HTML .= '<div class="content">';
    $HTML .= '<h4>' . get_the_title($post_id) . '</h4>';
    $HTML .= '<p>' . get_the_excerpt($post_id) . '</p>';
    $HTML .= '</div>';
    $HTML .= '</div>';
    
    return $HTML; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no problem with using this shortcode `[posts id="1,2,3,4"]`, the only thing left for you to do is create an array from the id attribute and loop it, like this.

```php
add_shortcode( 'posts', 'posts_shortcode' );
function posts_shortcode($atts) {
    
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => ''
    ), $atts );
    
    $HTML  = '<div class="posts">';

    foreach (explode(',', $atts['id']) as $post_id) {
        // because now we loop all ids and it can be multiple ids
        // it would be best to warp each one in its own container
        $HTML .='<div class="post">';

        $HTML .= '<div class="thumb">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'medium') . '</div>';
        $HTML .= '<div class="content">';
        $HTML .= '<h4>' . get_the_title($post_id) . '</h4>';
        $HTML .= '<p>' . get_the_excerpt($post_id) . '</p>';
        $HTML .= '</div>';

        // this is the closing tag for our "post" container
        $HTML. ='</div>'; // <div class="post">
    }

    $HTML .= '</div>';
    
    return $HTML; 
}
```

The main container `<div class="posts">` and its closing tag are outside of the loop because we only want them once.

I'm not sure why you made the varialbe that containes the html all capital letters but for PHP variables, the conventions, is all lowercase letters with underscore, no capital letters.
You are free to use what ever you want of course, but I just wanted to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks, Buttered_toast for your quick reply. Unfortunately, it has not yet brought the desired effect and only two posts are displayed although I have assigned 4 IDs. One of the displayed posts is the post itself, in which the shortcode is embedded. 

Maybe I think too complicated. I am looking for a simple solution to display selected posts by ID with a shortcode. As in the example, this should then contain the title, the thumbnail, the excerpt and the category. This shortcode should then be included in posts or on product pages.

I think capitals are a typical german thing ;)

Comment: @cobi Make sure the id attribute doesn't contain any spaces, in your question its `[posts id=1, 2, 3,4]` in my example its `[posts id="1,2,3,4"]`

Comment: I have just checked this and unfortunately it still does not work. Only two posts are displayed and one of them is the post itself in which the shortcode is integrated.

Comment: Dont know why, but it suddenly works 